# text File Dictionary Java

Tags: java, file, text

Im coding a dictionary in java that the user inputs the words and they are stored in a .txt file in alphabetical order. When I use the SortWords method on its own it works fine, but when I combine it with the Option1Method which adds words to the dictionary it dosent work. Its like it changes the file type of the text file or something?? Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public static void Option1Method() throws IOException {
    FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("wordlist.txt", true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
    String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word");

    out.println(word);
    out.close();

    aFileWriter.close();

    String inputFile = "wordlist.txt";
    String outputFile = "wordlist.txt";
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    String inputLine;
    List<String> lineList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lineList.add(inputLine);
    }
    fileReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lineList);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(outputFile);
    PrintWriter out1 = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
    for (String outputLine : lineList) {
        out.println(outputLine);
    }
    out1.flush();
    out1.close();
    fileWriter.close();
}
```

Comment: can you please properly format your code?

Comment: Sorry only new to this. How is it supposed to be formatted??

Comment: That should get you started

Comment: Also it would help a great deal if you can reduce the program to just the parts that create the problem (for instance drop the code that handles options that aren't involved in opening, writing and saving)

Answer (score 1):

Ok Because I couldn't let this question go unanswered here is a simple example of how you might do this using some built in classes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class q15664563 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String wordlist = "wordlist.txt";
    if(args.length == 1 && args[0].toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'l') {
      //List Words
      SortedSet<String> dictionary = load(wordlist);
      for(String word : dictionary) {
        System.out.println(word);
      }
    } else if(args.length == 2 && args[0].toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'a') {
      //Add Word
      SortedSet<String> dictionary = load(wordlist);

      dictionary.add(args[1].toLowerCase());

      save(dictionary, wordlist);
    } else {
      System.err.println("Correct usage:");
      System.err.println(" q15664563 LIST       --lists all words");
      System.err.println(" q15664563 ADD [word] --adds word to list");
    }
  }

  private static void save(SortedSet<String> dictionary, String wordlist) throws IOException {
    FileWriter file = new FileWriter(wordlist);
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(file);

    for(String word : dictionary) {
      writer.append(word);
      writer.newLine();
    }

    writer.close();
    file.close();
  }

  private static SortedSet<String> load(String wordlist) throws IOException {
    SortedSet<String> dictionary = new TreeSet<String>();
    FileReader file = new FileReader(wordlist);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    String word;

    while((word = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      dictionary.add(word);
    }

    reader.close();
    file.close();
    return dictionary;
  }
}
```

Some things to point out with this code, reading and writing are two separate operations so to keep things clean it helps to put them in their own functions (this is a matter of opinion of course).  Also, as is so often the case there are data types that will help you, and [`TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) is a great example of one.  It implements the [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) interface and is alphabetical every time you iterate through ti (actually it's alphabetical every time you insert into it, something to keep in mind as the set grows in length).  Given this property if you wanted to optimize you may only need to use `TreeSet` when the list might change it's alphabetic order (on insert).  When listing you would read the file line by line knowing that it was in the correct order.  If you did this then you would no longer have a generic `load()` method that you could use in both instances (something to consider when trading simplicity of design for performance).